# gap between keyboard and textview during animation

Tags: ios7, uiviewanimation, uikeyboard, nslayoutconstraint

I want to adjust the height of a textview when the keyboard appears. In iOS 7 this can be done by adjusting the NSLayoutConstraint between the textview and the bottomLayoutGuide of the view controller.

That works fine with the code below except for one detail. During the animation the textview runs ahead of the keyboard and a wide gap appears. Similar during the keyboardWillHide method.

The cause for this "bug" is probably because the keyboard starts from the very bottom of the screen while the textview starts higher up due to the height of the toolbar.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
-(void) keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *) notification
{
//update constraints
CGRect keyboardFrame = [[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
CGRect convertedKeyboardFrame = [[self view] convertRect:keyboardFrame
                                        fromView:nil];
CGRect toolbarFrame = [[[self navigationController] toolbar] frame];
CGRect convertedToolbarFrame = [[self view] convertRect:toolbarFrame
                                                fromView:nil];
CGFloat toolbarAdjustment = (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait([self interfaceOrientation])) ? CGRectGetHeight(convertedToolbarFrame) :CGRectGetWidth(convertedToolbarFrame);

[[_textView bottomSpaceConstraint] setConstant:CGRectGetHeight(convertedKeyboardFrame) - toolbarAdjustment];


//animate change
for (UIView *view in [[self view] subviews])
{
    [view setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
}

[UIView animateWithDuration:[[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue]
                      delay:0  //0.2 as possible hack, otherwise a gap appears between keyboard and textview
                    options:[[[notification userInfo] valueForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue]
                 animations:^{
                     for (UIView *view in [[self view] subviews])
                     {
                         [view layoutIfNeeded];
                     }

                 }
                 completion:NULL];
```

}

Comment: Quick cheat to avoid your bug (might even look neat): Have your bottom bar animate down off of the screen before bringing the keyboard up.

Answer (score 1):

The delay is probably caused by calling `layoutIfNeeded` repeatedly in a loop.

In the animation block, just send `layoutIfNeeded` to the root view, i.e., `self.view`. Sending `layoutIfNeeded` to the root view will take care of the entire view hierarchy. So get rid of the loop.

I question if the call to `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` is necessary; if it is, it only needs to be sent to the root view.

Also, try eliminating the animation options parameter

```
options:0
```

Comment: The code still works after incorporating your remarks. Thanks for the improvement. 

But the issue remains. It's not that there is a delay. It's that the animation curve is not the same as the keyboard. The textview will have reached its destination point before the keyboard.

Comment: @user965972 updated answer with new idea… eliminate animation option.

Comment: No, that makes no difference.